# How to view content of emacs autosave file

Tags: emacs, terminal, autosave, data-recovery, file-recovery

How do I directly see the content of an emacs autosave file, without implementing a file recovery operation?

That is, suppose I created a file with 'emacs foo', then emacs crashed, so I'm left with no file named 'foo' (since it never was saved) but with a file '#foo#'.  When I type 'more #foo#', I get "Missing filename", as though the more command doesn't even see the #foo# part of the command.

I just want to see the text in #foo# so I can copy it out by hand without risking something going wrong in the file recovery process (eg #foo# getting overwritten by a new autosave operation).

(I'm using Terminal on OSX.)

Comment: You can try to open the auto-save file in emacs `C-x C-f #foo#`. No harm done if you do not modify the original in the case that it is initially loaded by some lisp package. Maybe, you should start emacs with `emacs -Q` to avoid stuff like loading of a session file and so on. If you want to stick with `more` the hint of `wax-reggea` is helpful. ('#' is the comment character in `sh` and `bash`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash or another shell use '#' as comment character, try :

```
more "#foo#"
```